# How to declare a variable shared between examples in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, variables, rspec

Suppose I have the following spec:

```
describe Thing do
  it 'can read data' do
    @data = get_data_from_file  # [ '42', '36' ]
    expect(@data.count).to eq 2
  end

  it 'can process data' do
    expect(@data[0].to_i).to eq 42  # Fails because @data is nil
  end
end
```

All I wanted is to have a variable shared in the given *describe* or *context*. I would write a value in one example and read it in another. How do I do that?

Comment: did you get a good solution for this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should use `before(:each)` or `before(:all)` block:

```
describe Thing do
  before(:each) do
    @data = get_data_from_file  # [ '42', '36' ]
  end

  it 'can read data' do
    expect(@data.count).to eq 2
  end

  it 'can process data' do
    expect(@data[0].to_i).to eq 42
  end
end
```

The difference is that `before(:each)` will be executed for each case separately and `before(:all)` once before all examples in this `describe/context`. I would recommend you to prefer `before(:each)` over `before(:all)`, because each example will be isolated in this case which is a good practice.

There are rare cases when you want to use `before(:all)`, for example if your `get_data_from_file` has a long execution time, in this case you can, of course, sacrifice tests isolation in favor of speed. But I want to aware you, that when using `before(:all)`, modification of your `@data` variable in one test(`it` block) will lead to unexpected consequences for other tests in `describe/context` scope because they will share it.

`before(:all)` example:

```
describe MyClass do
  before(:all) do
    @a = []
  end

  it { @a << 1; p @a }
  it { @a << 2; p @a }
  it { @a << 3; p @a }
end
```

Will output:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
```

**UPDATED**

To answer you question

```
describe MyClass do
  before(:all) do
    @a = []
  end

  it { @a = [1]; p @a }
  it { p @a }
end
```

Will output

```
[1]
[]
```

Because in first `it` you are locally assigning instance variable @a, so it isn't same with @a in `before(:all)` block and isn't visible to other `it` blocks, you can check it, by outputting `object_id`s. So only modification will do the trick, assignment will cause new object creation.

So if you are assigning variable multiple times you should probably end up with one `it` block and multiple expectation in it. [It is acceptable, according to best practices.](http://betterspecs.org/#single)

Comment: Thank you. The idea is that I want to set a variable in one _example_ and read/update it in _another_ within the same 'describe' or 'context' block. For some reason the solution you proposed isn't working.

Comment: @AndreyEsperanza did you try `before(:all)`?

Comment: Yep. Of course, I gave an overly simplified example. Now I'm figuring out what can be wrong with the real spec.

Comment: @AndreyEsperanza I've just tested and added corresponding example to my answer. Maybe you should show us your code.

Comment: Your example works, but this is not what I need. How about this:

    `it { @a = [1] };  it { p @a }  # [], not [1]`

Comment: Thanks so much for this awesome answer. I just wanted to point out an important "gotcha" - your variable _must be_ declared as an instance variable (i.e. using an `@`), otherwise this will not work.

Answer (score 17):

This is really the purpose of the [RSpec let helper](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) which allows you to do this with your code:

```
...
describe Thing do
  let(:data) { get_data_from_file }

  it 'can read data' do
     expect(data.count).to eq 2
  end

  it 'can process data' do
     expect(data[0].to_i).to eq 42
  end

end
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as you see from the question above, the idea is to set a variable in one example and read/update it in another, within the same 'describe' or 'context' block.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. How I solved it was by using factory_girl gem.

Here's the basics:

create a factory (here's a code snippet:

```
require 'factory_girl'
require 'faker' # you can use faker, if you want to use the factory to generate fake data

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :generate_data, class: MyModule::MyClass do
    key 'value'
  end
end
```

Now after you made the factory you need to make a Model that looks like this:

```
Module MyModule
  class MyClass
    attr_accessor :key

    #you can also place methods here to call from your spec test, if you wish
    # def self.test
        #some test
    # end
  end
end
```

Now going back to your example you can do something like this:

```
describe Thing do
  before(:all) do
  @data = FactoryGirl.build(:generate_data)
  end

  it 'can read data' do
     @data.key = get_data_from_file  # [ '42', '36' ]
     expect(@data.key.count).to eq 2
  end

  it 'can process data' do
     expect(@data.key[0].to_i).to eq 42  # @data will not be nil. at this point. whatever @data.key is equal to last which was set in your previous context will be what data.key is here
  end

end
```

Anyways, good luck let us know, if you got some other solution!